# Split check_output return value

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to run a unix command using python, I have got the code to return the value I want, but does not seem to let me split the value on the delimiter that I have specified

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

def RunFPing(command):
    output = check_output(command.split(" "))
    output = str(output).split(" : ")
    return output

print RunFPing("fping -C 1 -q 192.168.1.25")
```

The output I get is:

```
10.1.30.10 : 29.00
['']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that `fping` is writing to stderr. To capture both stderr and stdout output using `check_output`, use

```
output = check_output(command.split(" "),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

In your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

def RunFPing(command):
    output = check_output(command.split(" "),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
    output = str(output).split(" : ")
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print RunFPing("fping -C 1 -q 192.168.1.25")
```

will result in

```
192.168.1.25 : 0.04
['192.168.1.25', '0.04\n']
```